# less a file with JSON rows - how to highlight/colorize the rows?

Tags: linux, logs, json, less, highlighting

I have log files with json rows inside - less displays it as just plain text
Can I colorize the output with less abilities?
As well as I didn't find any less-compatible third party tool with json highlighting
Example of such file

```
{"date":"2021-10-21 16:09:54", "perf":{"action":"getTimelineByClient", "time":46.2}}
{"date":"2021-10-22 16:09:54", "perf":{"action":"getTimelineByClient", "time":46.2}}
{"date":"2021-10-23 16:09:54", "perf":{"action":"getTimelineByClient", "time":46.2}}
```

Edit
@glennjackman kindly pointed to https://github.com/sharkdp/bat - great tool, not fit for my needs, but maybe will be helpful for the other. `bat` firstly parses the file and afterwards tries to show it. 120k of short json rows were pretty heavy for my machine

Comment: it's unclear what you are asking, which part of json file do you want to highlight? whole file? part of file? part of elements? specifc element? would you please [edit] your question and clarify. see also `man less`.

Comment: Just as I mentioned it - I want to colorize the less output, everything I need from less to show  
`man less` has no support of reading jsons

Comment: `bat` is good for this: https://github.com/sharkdp/bat

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman. `bat` is a great tool, but it parses the whole file - humble 120k rows put down the machine :)  I would like to colorize the output of the pager: the pager efficiently manages log file and only the shown screen is json-parsed

Answer (score 1):

You could colorize your JSON output with `jq`

```bsh
cat log | jq .
```

The output is pretty but if you you don't want it you can use `--compact-output` (short: `-c`) option.

To use a piped command like `less` after `jq`, you need use `--color-output` (short: `-C`) option.

`less` command accept to reproduce ANSI sequences with `-r` option.

```bsh
cat log | jq -cC . | less -r
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks!
It means `jq` needs to parse the whole file - it's pretty big files, is there an option for a pager like less?

Comment: You can try `--stream` jq option but output is really differrent